# SIPO Shift register compatible with SPI bus?

Tags: spi, shift-register

I'm trying to drive LEDs from a shift register that shares a bus with several other components. It seems like most options for SIPO shift registers don't have the equivalent of a chip select line, making them difficult to work with on a shared bus. I've found the 74HC589 for my PISO needs which has the serial output through a controlled 3 state buffer. is there a chip like this for SIPO, or do i need to buffer the serial input with a seperate chip?

Comment: Doesn't the [74HC595](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54hc595-sp.pdf) do this? Or am I missing something important? (I'm sure I must be, as I can't imagine you missing this in a search.)

Comment: I don't think so, if the 595 takes clock and MOSI lines from the bus, it will load data intended for other peripherals into the shift register. The best solution might be to just use a seperate chip to buffer these two lines, conditional on a CS signal.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you'd considered it for your application. I don't have another suggestion, so best wishes.

Comment: @harmoncleary please post a schematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '595 can be used with SPI; just connect the chip select line (/CS) to the output register clock (RCLK). The shift register inputs (SER, SRCLK) can be shared.

All data on the shared bus will be shifted into the shift register. But this is not a problem; only the rising edge on /CS will output the bits that were most recently shifted in.

[image: SN74HCS595 functional block diagram]

<sup>(source: [SN74HCS595 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74HCS595))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The 74HC595 is SPI compatible.

Or rather, the other way around, because how history went, 74HC595 came before SPI and SPI is just an interface for serial peripherals and 74HC595 is a serial peripheral.